# List of things we made

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests

I have a presentation, and I am trying to make a headline for the slide that describes the page of things we made, I currently have it titled "things we made" but I don't think that is aduequate.

What are some others ways to title it

Comment: If it "describes the things you made, call it "things we made" and be up front.

Comment: Don’t do Powerpoint presentations. They are evil. People hate them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider using [our portfolio](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/portfolio).

> A company's portfolio of products or designs is their range of
>   products or designs.
>
> *The company has continued to invest heavily in a strong portfolio of products.*